# Alternatives for generics and interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, c++-cli

*First of all: I am using C++-CLI, but, as users have asked, I think this also applies to C#, that's why I have added this tag.*

I have following function

```
static CFiducial^ CFiducial::GetCommonBase (array<CFiducial^>^ i_aoFiducial)
{
  if (!i_aoFiducial || i_aoFiducial->Length <= 0)
    return gcnew CFiducial;

  CFiducial^ oFiducial;
  for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < i_aoFiducial->Length; iCnt++)
  {
    if (!i_aoFiducial[iCnt]) continue;
    if (oFiducial)
      oFiducial= oFiducial->GetCommonBase (i_aoFiducial[iCnt]);
    else
      i_aoFiducial[iCnt]->CopyTo (oFiducial);
  }
  return oFiducial;
}
```

which is used in identical way in multiple classes.
*(There is another member function `GetCommonBase (CFiducial^)` which compares the member variables content to the content of the members of the passed object and returns a new object with only those members set that are equal. See below for an example).*

I now was going to outsource all implementations of this static function and move them to a central location, having only one implementation there. I have tried generics and interfaces, but both fail:

- generics don't work because I can't call methods on generics.
- interfaces fail because the functions defined in the interface need to take an instance of the object that the interface later is bound to.

This is the interface was going to use:

```
public interface class ICommonBase
{
  ICommonBase^        GetCommonBase (ICommonBase^);
  void                CopyTo (ICommonBase^%);
};
```

I could not implement `GetCommonBase (ICommonBase^)` in the actual classes, I need to implement `GetCommonBase (CLASSNAME^)`, but that does not match the definition in the interface.

**Is there a way around this?

Is there another alternative to interface and generics?**
I still want to avoid copy and paste of that function into each class where I need it.

**Edit**

Sample of the member function `GetCommonBase()`, which is from a different class, where inheritance is actually used, therefore the name. The problem described above has nothing to do with inheritance though.

```
CImageObject^ CImgObjCircle::GetCommonBase (CImageObject^ i_oImageObject)
{
  CImageObject^ oImgObj;
  if (!i_oImageObject)
  {
    this->CopyTo (oImgObj);
    return oImgObj;
  }
  oImgObj = CImageObject::GetCommonBase (i_oImageObject);

  CImgObjCircle^ i_oImgObj = dynamic_cast<CImgObjCircle^>(i_oImageObject);
  if (!i_oImgObj)
    return oImgObj;
  CImgObjCircle^ oImgObjLocal = gcnew CImgObjCircle;
  oImgObj->CopyTo (oImgObjLocal);
  if (m_oDiameterX == i_oImgObj->m_oDiameterX) oImgObjLocal->m_oDiameterX = m_oDiameterX;

  return oImgObjLocal;
}
```

Comment: Why do you used the C# tag ?

Comment: because it should also apply to c#

Comment: But this syntax is pure C++, for transforming to c# you may create another topic.

Comment: @HimBromBeere This is C++CLI, also known as c++.net or Visual C++

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Please explain what you want to do

Comment: @Alireza: _I now was going to outsource all implementations of this static function and move them to a central location_  but it failed, as described above.

Comment: No, I mean please explain what the function should do. The problem is while I can see what the function does for a single class, I don't understand what should it do when it is implemented for a base class that others inherit from and how should it be different from your current version. Please explain the function precisely.

Comment: This function is _not_ a member function. It is `static` (added the keyword later, sorry). Therefore I am not using inheritance. It's purpose is iterative calling member functions for copying and comparing.

Comment: Pretty hard to imagine the usefulness of this code.  Collapsing an entire array into a single object makes little sense.  It *looks* like a bandaid for not using the *virtual* keyword enough.  Outcome is random.

Comment: @HansPassant: It makes a lot of sense in my case. The member function `GetCommonBase()` compares the member variables content to the content of the members of the passed object and returns a new object with only those members set that are equal. The others remain at their default value. It has absolutely nothing to do with inheritance!

Comment: Oh, could not have guessed at that in a hundred years.  Do you have somebody that reviews your code?  Recommended.  He'd probably suggest avoiding the "common base" term.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, the content of the new object is just the "common base" of 2 others. I am using inheritance often, but I didn't expect this name to cause confusion. Do you have a better name for it? Maybe I rename it "GetCommonData". BTW: as written in the post, the same-named function in the code is a different one! Don't mix that up, there's no recursion.

Comment: @HansPassant The name originally came from finding the common base class of two classes, together with getting the common data. See the edited post. In the case above the inheritance part is not used. And it's not used at all in the static function, which I am trying to outsource.